# ERROR: Cannot read property 'createTable' of undefined, queryInterface is undefiend too

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, migration

this is the code in migration file (sequalize)

```
const { DataTypes } =  require('sequelize');

module.exports = {
  up: async ({context: queryInterface}) => {
    console.log("queryInterface", queryInterface);
    await queryInterface.createTable('model_fields', {
```

and on running command `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`
I'm getting this error

```
aman@aman-linux:~/Projects/xxx/xxx-backend$ npx sequelize-cli db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.20.0, CLI: 6.4.1, ORM: 6.21.2]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Using environment "development".
== 20220811-start: migrating =======
queryInterface undefined

ERROR: Cannot read property 'createTable' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `queryInterface` is not defined. You need to import the module in order to use it's content